# Translate structured data to python array of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-conversion

I have this input file containing data structured like this:

```
[
    {
        "raw": "blah blah",
        "entities": [
            {
                "offset": 100,
                "end": 145,
                "entityId": "CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER"
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        "raw": "blah blah",
        "entities": [
            {
                "offset": 200,
                "end": 300,
                "entityId": "CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What is the most appropriate way to translate it into this format (a python array of tuples)?

```
[
    (
        "blah blah",
        {"entities": [(100, 145, "CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER")]},
    ),
    (
        "blah blah",
        {"entities": [(200, 300, "CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER")]},
    ),
]
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple enough if you want to create a new array with same information.

`ele['raw']` provides the `blah blah`

`[tuple(ele['entities'][0].values())]`  provides the `[(100, 145, 'CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER')]` as a list

```
arr = [{"raw": "blah blah","entities": [{"offset": 100,"end": 145,"entityId": "CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER"}]},{"raw": "blah blah", "entities": [{"offset": 200,"end": 300,"entityId": "CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER"}]}]
ans = [(ele['raw'],{'entities':[tuple(ele['entities'][0].values())] }) for ele in k]
```

out:

```
[('blah blah', {'entities': [(100, 145, 'CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER')]}),
('blah blah', {'entities': [(200, 300, 'CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER')]})]
```

Comment: Thanks @venky__, almost there, but entities should be a list of tuples rather than just a list, e.g. `[(200, 300, "CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER")]` rather than `[200, 300, 'CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER']`. This also doesn't handle entities with 0 elements, or entities with more than 1 element

Comment: @Rory Updated my answer try now.

Comment: Thanks @venky__, but this doesn't handle entities with 0 elements, or entities with more than 1 element

Comment: You should add these testcases in your original question and you can definitely add if statement to ignore 0 element cases .

Comment: This is the correct answer:  with open('input/training_data.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
            a = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
            training_data = []
            for ele in a:
                raw = ele['raw']
                entities = []
                for e in ele['entities']:
                    entity = (e["offset"], e["end"], e["entityId"])
                    entities.append(entity)
                training_data.append((raw, {'entities': entities}))